# Forget your sin and move forward

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, sin, tawba

Should we forget our previous sin after true repntance as it is not allowing to move forward i m totally stucked always thinks about previou sin. I m not able to focus on my study what should i do??

Answer (score 1):

yes, you move forward and think about your previous sin and do not do them again. if you repentance with true heart Allah Almighty absolutely forgive your previous sins.